# Efficiently generate 2^n combinations (/w java)

Tags: java, optimization, binary

I'm trying to generate all 2^n as efficiently as possible (and save them to an array), like
    0001
    0010
    0011
    etc.
Where n could be up to 15.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int N = 15;
    int m = (int) Math.pow(2, N) - 1;
    int[][] array = new int[m][N];
    int arrLength = array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        String str = String.format("%" + N + "s", Integer.toBinaryString(i + 1)).replace(' ', '0');
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            array[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(j));
        }
    }
    final long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    double sec = (double) duration / 1000000000.0;
    System.out.println(sec);
}
```

Any suggestion on how i can do this faster?
As of now, my timer says it takes ~0.1 to ~0.12

Comment: 1) If you want `2^n` combinations, why do you create array with size `2^n-1`? --- 2) Since `m` is already the array size, `arrLength = array.length` is rather redundant. --- 3) `Math.pow(2, N)` would be better written as `1 << N`. --- 4) When you divide a `long` value with a `double` value, the `long` value is automatically [promoted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) to `double`, so no need to cast it.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the feedback, i forgot to mention that i wanted to skip the first combo (0000)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String processing tends to be slow (typically requires loops and allocations). You can just shift the interesting bit to position 0 instead, then cut off higher bit using bitwise and with 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        array[i][j] = (i >> j) & 1;
    }
}
```

p.s. I have left out adding 1 to i, wasn't sure if this was intended in the original code, should be straightforward to add as needed.

Comment: Thanks alot! Exactly what i needed (as you say str processing takes time)! yes it was intended! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

My most efficient way would be by not generating them at all, which roughly takes... 0 nanoseconds.

These strings are the textual representation of all integers from 0 to 2^n-1, for which enumeration is no mystery. There is no need to store them (in an array), as the keys would be the same as the indexes.

If you have compelling reasons to process them as strings, you can perform the conversion when required, with you own routine or with toBinaryString.

Depending on your application, f.i. string lookup, another option can be to turn the given string to its integer value. If the goal is to check presence/absence of items in a given combination, binary masks will do an effective job.